# Taking too much time with large excel file with python

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel file with 4.95 MB. I am trying to read this file with openpyxl
and perform some excel formula in this file. It is working great with small files. But as Soon as I started working with the large file. It takes too much time as if seems like it moves to an infinite Condition. Kindly let me know with some approach or what modification should I do in this piece of code.

```
import openpyxl
import os
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter
#reading the file i.e. 4.5 Mb
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"type_example.xlsx")
Sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('sheet1')


for row,cellObj in enumerate(Sheet["C"],1):
    cellObj.value='=IF(OR(B{0}="J", B{0} ="U", B{0} ="s"),"s", IF(OR(B{0} ="I", B{0} ="M", B{0} ="N", B{0}="O", B{0} ="Q", B{0} ="U", B{0} ="V"), "J", "des"))'.format(row)
    Sheet.cell(row=1, column=3).value = 'Dt'
    #path to save file 
    wb.save(r'\Documents\test_1.xlsx')
```

Comment: How long is "too much time" ? How many rows are there in the file ?

Comment: @Rohit jha simply use pandas library http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15/index.html

Comment: @reportgunner its around 273025

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi thanks! But it doesn't help

Comment: Any other approach or change in code

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look around and found that the issue may be because you're going cell-by-cell.

It seems that openpyxl will basically do a linear search through the entire document to find your desired cell if you do things like that (which is not ideal), and you need to use a generator if you want to speed it up.

It doesn't look too hard, but I'm not particularly skilled in python. So, rather than try to explain the concept myself, I'll leave you this:

https://blog.davep.org/2018/06/02/a_little_speed_issue_with_openpyxl.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: As in the article wasn't helpful or you tried using generators and they didn't help?

Comment: using generators didn't help